# How to reference the element that was clicked in the IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

How to hide the p that was clicked in the code? Existing new ones?

```js
(function($) {
  $('body').on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target == $('button')[0]) {
      $('body').append('<p class="myp">text</p>')
    }

    if ($(event.target).attr('class') == 'myp') {
      // hide the clicked p
    }
  })
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<p class="myp">text</p>
<p class="myp">text</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your logic work to detect the `p` which was clicked, use `hasClass()`, then `hide()`, like this:

```js
(function($){
  $('body').on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target == $('button')[0]) {
      $('body').append('<p class="myp">text</p>')
    }

    if ($(event.target).hasClass('myp')) {
      $(event.target).hide();
    }
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<p class="myp">text</p>
<p class="myp">text</p>
```

*However*, I presume you're attempting to work with the click event on the `body` in this manner because the child elements are dynamically generated. As such there's a *much* better way of achieving what you're doing here; delegated event handlers:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('body').append('<p class="myp">text</p>');
  }).on('click', '.myp', function() {
    $(this).hide();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<p class="myp">text</p>
<p class="myp">text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why with `event.target` .Just target with class or id of element to initiate the function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').on('click', function() {
    $('body').append('<p class="myp">text</p>')
  })
}).on('click', 'p.myp', function() {
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>

<p class="myp">text</p>
<p class="myp">text</p>
```